# mod rewrite of query strings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say I wanted `http://domain.com/product/?id=123` to become `http://domain.com/product/foo`, how do I do that in `.htaccess`? I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^/product$  /product/foo    [NC,L,R=301]
```

Suggestions?

NOTE: I do not need to capture the value of the `id` parameter as I will not use it in the new URL.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fisher

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123 [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/$  /product/foo    [NC,L,R=301]
```

1. Showing RewriteEngine and RewriteBase
2. Remove `$` in RewriteCond
3. Remove `/` in RewriteRule

When I go to `http://localhost/fisher/product/?id=123`, nothing happens. The URL remains the same.

Comment: Try getting rid of the forward-slash at the start of your RewriteRule pattern. Paths do not begin with a forward-slash in a .htaccess file because .htaccess files are executed for the directory in which they reside. (Note that RewriteRule paths do begin with a forward-slash in a httpd.conf file.)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and restart the browser then try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fisher

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123 [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/?$ product/foo? [NC,L,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine then change `R=302` to `R=301`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your solution? Keep in mind that `id=123` might redirect to `product/foo` while `id=999` might redirect to `product/bar`.

Comment: Made an edit to make it specific for `id=123` only. I am using a mod_rewrite variable `%{THE_REQUEST}` which represents original HTTP request as received by Apache web server from browser.

Comment: Why not use `QUERY_STRING`? Also, I tried your condition/rule and went to `http://localhost/fisher/product/?id=123`. Nothing happened. It did not change my URL.

Comment: @snoopy76: Before your edit you didn't mention `/fisher` before the URL hence it didn't work. Try the edit now.